# When Side Bar shows up still can see other buttons in the page through the side bar

Tags: css, reactjs

When Side Bar shows up still can see other buttons in the page through the side bar. Can anyone help me with this issue

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GPJC.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvjbF.png)

Comment: please share some code

Comment: Its difficult for us to help when you are posting images instead of code . Please add some code and also explain clearly what the current behaviour and what is the expected behaviour as well .

Comment: If you mean `buy now <3 ` button, you need to check its z-index, should be less than that of sidebar.

Comment: @AbhishekSharma Thank you mate.. I went through your response and it worked

Answer (score 0):

**You should try this**

Wrap your side bar inside a div then make the width of div 100% & give a background color(with opacity:0.9).
You will get a better user experience.

**Note:** You will have to write some script to disable your side bar when some user clicks on that div's background.

Comment: I hope this will help you!!